# Login to website using MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0

Tags: authentication, web

Need help with logon website using MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0 for the specific website below. I have the code to extract the tables on the website but need help logging on please. Would really like a pop up msg to confirm a successful logon. Below if my attempt that I "borrowed" from another post. Thanks in advance.

```
Dim xml As Object
Dim html As Object
Dim text As Object

Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

Set html = CreateObject("htmlFile")

With xml
  .Open "POST", "https://flightaware.com/account/session", False
  .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
  .send "flightaware_username = MyEmail@yahoo.com & flightaware_password = MyPassword"
  .Open "GET", "https://flightaware.com/account/session", False
  .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
  .send
End With
```